# I have added webpack-server still it shows this error while running npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start

Enterprise-User-Management@1.0.0 start C:\Users\503100765\Documents\USM\user-management

> set NODE_ENV=development && set API_ROOT=http://localhost:7010/api/v1 && webpack-serve --config ./config/webpack.dev.js

'webpack-serve' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Enterprise-User-Management@1.0.0 start: `set NODE_ENV=development && set API_ROOT=http://localhost:7010/api/v1 && webpack-serve --config ./config/webpack.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Enterprise-User-Management@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\503100765\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-01-10T14_08_32_164Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

It’s webpack-server but not webpack-serve. r is missing in your command line script

Change

```
   set NODE_ENV=development && set API_ROOT=http://localhost:7010/api/v1 && webpack-serve --config ./config/webpack.dev.js
```

To

```
  set NODE_ENV=development && set API_ROOT=http://localhost:7010/api/v1 && webpack-server --config ./config/webpack.dev.js
```